# How to negotiate sink before eos event?

Tags: python-3.x, gstreamer, pygobject

How to negotiate sink before eos event? 
Please, explain me what i'm doing wrong.
Trying to run example from tutorial 8 using Python:
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/short-cutting-the-pipeline.html

Error output:

```
    ...
    0:00:00.117266000 78270 0x7ff68399a6d0 FIXME                default gstutils.c:3902:gchar *gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal(GstPad *, GstElement *, const gchar *):<app_source:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
    0:00:00.119250000 78270 0x7ff68399a6d0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2939:void gst_base_src_loop(GstPad *):<app_source> error: Internal data stream error.
    0:00:00.119260000 78270 0x7ff68399a6d0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2939:void gst_base_src_loop(GstPad *):<app_source> error: streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
    0:00:00.119408000 78270 0x7ff68399ade0 WARN           audiobasesink gstaudiobasesink.c:1119:gst_audio_base_sink_wait_event:<audio_sink> error: Sink not negotiated before eos event.
    Error received from element app_source: gst-stream-error-quark: Internal data stream error. (1)
    Debugging information: gstbasesrc.c(2939): void gst_base_src_loop(GstPad *) (): /GstPipeline:test-pipeline/GstAppSrc:app_source:
    streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had entered a wrong audio caps for the appsrc input data. So I changed audio capabilities string from this:

```
AUDIO_CAPS = 'audio/x-raw, rate=(int)44100, format=(string)S16, ' \
            'channels=(int)1'
```

to this:

```
AUDIO_CAPS = 'audio/x-raw, rate=(int)44100, format=(string)S16LE, ' \
            'channels=(int)1, layout=(str)interleaved'
```